# How to make unitypackage from allseen alliance's android sdk?

Tags: unity, android, multiplayer

Im making an offline multiplayer for Android device by Unity and I found only one way to do this is the allseenalliance sdk. After download its from [here](https://allseenalliance.org/developers/download) I found that to use it I need to create an .unitypackage file but I cant understand the tutorial they give

```
> Open a CMD window.
>     Add the path to Unity.exe (the Unity IDE) to your PATH, if it is not there already.
>         For example, set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor
>     CD to each "unity" folder in the SDK, and run the following command in each location:
>         Unity.exe -batchmode -nographics -quit -projectPath %CD% -exportPackage Assets AllJoyn.unitypackage
>     This command creates the AllJoyn.unitypackage file.
```

Please give me a noob tutorial for this or the package file, thanks.

p/s:Is there another way to connect mobile device without internet in unity3d?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based solely on the instructions and my reading comprehension, the following is a more easy to follow guide on how to accomplish those tasks.

---

1. Open the command prompt.

> This can be done many different ways based on your version of windows. The easiest
>   way would be by clicking: "Windows Key + R", then typing "cmd.exe",
>   then clicking "OK".
>
> ---

2. Run (type in the command prompt and hit enter) the command: **set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor**

> This command appends the location of the Unity Editor folder to your path variable.
>   Anything located in the PATH variable is checked when running a
>   program, so adding the path allows you to run the Unity.exe program
>   from anywhere, this is useful in Step 7.
>
> ---

3. Know where the SDK is located on your computer.

> You can cheat and look using the GUI if you would like.
>
> ---

4. Run the command: **CD "*location to SDK*"**

> Instead of putting "location to SDK", replace that with the path to
>   the SDK found in Step 3. If there are any spaces in this path, then include quotation marks around the entire path. This command tells the command prompt what directory to use when looking for programs by their name.
>
> ---

5. Run the command: **DIR**

> DIR allows you to see all of the files and folders in the Current
>   Directory (set in step 4). OR you can cheat and look using the GUI. Find a unity folder that you have not already done this process to.
>
> ---

6. Run the command: **CD "*name of unity folder*"**

> This sets your current directory to the unity folder located inside of
>   the sdk. Change 'name of unity folder' to the actual name of the folder in this directory.
>
> ---

7. Run the command: **Unity.exe -batchmode -nographics -quit -projectPath %CD% -exportPackage Assets AllJoyn.unitypackage**

---

8. Run the command: **CD..**

> This command changes the current directory to the parent of the
>   current directory.
>
> ---

9. Repeat steps 5 - 8 until all of the unity folders in the sdk have been completed.

---

p/s: If you have the android pro license with unity, you can use sockets to have two clients talk with each other over the lan. If you don't have a pro license, it sounds like a pain because .NET sockets are off the table... but even if that is the case, it sounds like this might help in making your own solution: [Mobile Socket Support with Unity3D](http://web.archive.org/web/20120723093724/http://devblog.twelve21.net/tutorials/mobile-socket-support-with-unity3d-basic-introduction/)